# How to prevent session timeout by using a jQuery Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, session

I try to put following code into bottom of HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var refreshTime = 300000;
    window.setInterval( function() {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            url: "custom url",
            success: function(data) {
            }
        });
    }, refreshTime );
</script>
```

And I need when it exceed session time (30000 ms), then refresh with "custom url".

But as I try, the page wouldn't refresh or redirect with "custom url" after pass 30000 ms or 5 minutes.

Am I correct to do this?

Thanks

Comment: _“But as I try, the page wouldn't refresh or redirect with "custom url" after pass 30000 ms or 5 minutes.”_ - well that’s because you implemented no such thing … And what you actually want here, is rather unclear - do you want to keep the session alive (by periodically making AJAX requests), or do you want to redirect somewhere else after that specified time? I can’t see both making much sense at the same time.

Comment: Seems like an XY problem, but if you want to refresh the page after 300 seconds:  `setTimeout(function() { location.href = location.href; }, 300000);`

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "session timeout", it's unlikely an ajax request will fix this.  Your code just gets the 'custom url' - but then does nothing with it, so won't "refresh" or "redirect" as you've not told it to do that.  You could update the html with the result of the ajax call or you could redirect to another page (without the need for ajax).

Comment: If you want to prevent a session timeout by creating artificial client side activity via javascript, you could just as easily increase the session timeout on your server application.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking - one redirects immediately, the other after 30s.  `window.location.` is the same as `location.` unless you have defined "location" as a local variable.

Comment: I need to prevent exceed of CPU usage on the server when search engine robots (bingbot) crawl over 30 minutes. This take the server heavily load. I need to limit them not loading over xx minutes and redirect them to another page. Not sure, this way could be solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following in **success** function of `ajax` call:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = 'your-url-here';
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not implemented any reload function.

```
var refreshTime = 300000;
    window.setInterval( function() {
      location.reload();//reload 
// window.location.href = "custom url"; to redirect

 }, refreshTime );
```